# Copying file from one location to another location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

would like to copy files from one location to another location in spring MVC web application, how to configure the path and read the path in a web appplication.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is a tag in your web.xml (or must be) that you can specify where your spring configurations are. The tag is < context-param > 

Here I give you an example:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The former configuration is in the WEB-INF folder, 
and the latter is in the WEB-INF/spring (as you may have noticed).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Apache Commons IO FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)